# Typescript treat JS array as object

Tags: typescript, typescript-definitions

I have a js function that outputs an array with 3 numbers.
Could I define a type/interface/whatever that will treat the array as an object.

So that `Somethig.GetVector().X` transpiles into `Something.GetVector()[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, TypeScript transpilation doesn't work that way.

You *can* define a TypeScript interface that *extends* an array:

```
interface ExtArr extends Array<string> {
  extProp?: string
}

const a: ExtArr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
a.extProp = 'quux'
```

However, the type information transpiles away to nothing - it's only used by TypeScript, not JavaScript.

Alternatively, you can define a function that converts the array into an object with friendly property names. It sounds like this is probably what you want for your use case:

```
const makeFriendly = (unfriendlyArray: string[] /* or whatever type */) => {
  const [ propName1, propName2, propName3 ] = unfriendlyArray

  return { propName1, propName2, propName3 }
}

makeFriendly(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']) // { propName1: "foo", propName2: "bar", propName3: "baz" }
```